# This CSS grid is not showing a grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

```css
<style>


  .d1{background:LightSkyBlue;}
  .d2{background:LightSalmon;}
  .d3{background:PaleTurquoise;}
  .d4{background:LightPink;}
  .d5{background:PaleGreen;}
  .d6{background-color: cornsilk;}

  .container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4,100px);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(2,50px);
    grid-gap: 10px 10px;
  }
</style>
```

```html
<html>
    </div class="container">
        <div class="d1"> 1 </div>
        <div class="d2"> 2 </div>
        <div class="d3"> 3 </div>
        <div class="d4"> 4 </div>
        <div class="d5"> 5 </div>
        <div class="d6"> 6 </div>
    </div>

</html>
```

this grid is not working please help. I go through lots of online resouses, but didn't found a solution. I think i add all the things that need to be in a grid.

Comment: `</div class="container">` should be `<div class="container">`. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0vrxz8am/)

Comment: This question is simple typo, you can delete the question

Answer (score 3):

That's because there's no opening tag for class container update your HTML to following:

```
<html>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="d1"> 1 </div>
        <div class="d2"> 2 </div>
        <div class="d3"> 3 </div>
        <div class="d4"> 4 </div>
        <div class="d5"> 5 </div>
        <div class="d6"> 6 </div>
    </div>
</html>
```